# ListviewArray Adaptor returns null pointer exception in customized layout

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

My problem is,  I could not show the `ArrayList` data in `ListView`. My need is I have to show `listview` in my customized layout file center part. I have used custom adapter to show the `listview`. I am retrieving `ListArray<String>` data from my local database. `Listview` adapter does not receive my database `ArrayList<String>` item. I have created separate class for `ListAdaptor` and also created a constructor for `ListAdaptor`.

I can able to show by extending `ListActivity`, But I have use `CustomAdaptor`. The following are my code, Please tell me where I did wrong code

***Layout file(Dashboard_Notify.xml)***

This is my customized layout xml file, In this page center i want to show listview data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dash_nav_bg_widout_brk_line"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dash_nav_bg1_not_select" />
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dash_nav_sep1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dash_nav_bg1_bday" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dash_nav_sep1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dash_nav_bg1_sms" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dash_midl_bg_notify"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="29 MAY" />
 <View
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:background="#8DB3E1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/List"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a"
            android:divider="#8DB3E1"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

</LinearLayout>




***//ListViewItem Row xml(BdayLlist.xml)***

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TableLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="127dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="id" />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="vennila" />

          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_Loc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location" />

         </LinearLayout>

             </TableRow>

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_BDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bday" />


            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_Day"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wednessday" />


             </TableRow>

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_toDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Today" />
          <TextView
               android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:id="@+id/test_Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="May 7" />

             </TableRow>


         </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity class(TodayList.java)***

```
package com.example.sampleparse;



import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TodayList extends Activity{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DbHelper dbh;
ListView lv;
private ArrayList<String> user_loc = new ArrayList<String>();

private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> user_id = new ArrayList<String>();

 ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

 TestAdaptor ta;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_notify);
          this.lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
            try{
        // BdayList();
                //Bname();
       //  displayData();
                 dbh=new DbHelper(this);
                 db=dbh.getWritableDatabase();
                 list=dbh.Bname();

                 String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];
                 stockArr = list.toArray(stockArr);
                 for(String s : stockArr)
                        System.out.println(s);
                // System.out.println(stockArr.toString());

                /* user_loc=dbh.BLocation();
                 String[] loc = new String[user_loc.size()];

                 for(String l : loc)
                     System.out.println(l);*/
                 //ta = new  TestAdaptor(TodayList.this, stockArr,loc );
                 ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
                 lv.setAdapter(la);
                /* ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.bdaylist, R.id.test_name, stockArr);*/

                       // setListAdapter(adapter);   

            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
     }



    public void Bname(){
         dbh=new DbHelper(this);
         db=dbh.getWritableDatabase();
         list=dbh.Bname();
         listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.bdaylist, list); 
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
     }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            super.onResume();
            //displayData();
        }


     //worked listView(){ code
     //should extends listActivity
     public void list(){
         dbh=new DbHelper(this);
         db=dbh.getWritableDatabase();
         list=dbh.Bname();

         String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];
         stockArr = list.toArray(stockArr);
         for(String s : stockArr)
                System.out.println(s);
        // System.out.println(stockArr.toString());
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.bdaylist, R.id.test_name, stockArr);
        //should uncomment the line
                //setListAdapter(adapter);   
     }

     public void displayData() {
            db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String formattedDate1 = df1.format(c.getTime());

                String sub = formattedDate1;
                String s1=sub.substring(0, 5);
                ArrayList<String> test=new ArrayList<String>();
           String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM " + dbh.TABLE_CONTACTS + " where dob = '" + s1 +"'";
            Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            user_id.clear();
            user_loc.clear();
            user_fName.clear();

            if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    user_id.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));

                    user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.EMP_NAME)));
                    user_loc.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.EMP_LOC)));
                    System.out.println("loc " + user_loc);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user_id.toString()+" "+ user_fName.toString()+ " "+ user_loc.toString(), 1000).show();
                    //user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ASSID)));
                    //user_dob.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_DOB)));

                    //user_mobno.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MOBNO)));
                    //user_email.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_EMAIL)));

                } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            ListAdapter disadpt = new ListAdapter(TodayList.this, user_fName );
            lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
            mCursor.close();
        }





     public void BdayList(){

         dbh=new DbHelper(this);
         db=dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        list= dbh.DOB();
        // listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.bdaylist, list);  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(TodayList.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);*/
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplrrow, list);
            lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     }

     private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
              for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
              String item = getItem(position);
              return mIdMap.get(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
              return true;
            }

          }

}
```

***Custom Adaptor class(ListAdaptor.java)***

```
package com.example.sampleparse;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> Name;
    private ArrayList<String> Assid;

    private ArrayList<String> Dob;
    private ArrayList<String> Mobno;
    private ArrayList<String> Email;
    private ArrayList<String> dept;
    private ArrayList<String> location;

    public ListAdapter(Context c,  ArrayList<String> name) {
        this.mContext = c;

        //this.id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    /*  this.Assid = assid;
        this.Dob = user_dob;
        this.Mobno = user_mobno;
        this.Email = user_email;
        this.dept = dept;*/
        //this.location = loc;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
    }
    public void setAllItems(ArrayList<String> paramArrayList) {
        this.Name.addAll(paramArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (child == null) {
            mHolder = new Holder();
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bdaylist, parent, false);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            /* localViewholder.categoryName = ((TextView) paramView
                        .findViewById(R.id.name));

                paramView.setTag(localViewholder);*/
        //  mHolder.
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_id);
            mHolder.txt_Name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_name);
            mHolder.txt_Loc = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_Loc);

            mHolder.txt_Bday = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_BDay);
            mHolder.txt_Day= (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_Day);
            mHolder.txt_Today= (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_toDay);
            mHolder.txt_Date = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.test_Date);

            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.txt_id.setText("id");
        mHolder.txt_Name.setText(Name.get(pos).indexOf(0));
        mHolder.txt_Loc.setText(":lov");

        mHolder.txt_Bday.setText("Birth Day");
        mHolder.txt_Day.setText("WEdness day");
        mHolder.txt_Today.setText("Today");
        mHolder.txt_Date.setText("May 7");
        mHolder.txt_Loc.setText("loc");
        return child;


    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_Name;
        TextView txt_Bday;

        TextView txt_Day;
        TextView txt_Today;
        TextView txt_Date;
        TextView txt_Loc;

    }

}
```

Please give me a solution, I spent stuck in this concept more than one day.

Comment: Please post your logcat output containing the NullPointerException. Also, indicate which line it is referencing in your above code.

Answer (score 0):

for(String s : stockArr)
                        System.out.println(s);
                // System.out.println(stockArr.toString());

```
            /* user_loc=dbh.BLocation();
             String[] loc = new String[user_loc.size()];

             for(String l : loc)
                 System.out.println(l);*/
             //ta = new  TestAdaptor(TodayList.this, stockArr,loc );
             ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
             lv.setAdapter(la);
```

There is a problem if i am not wrong you are setting your adapter recursively through the for loop just initailize only one time after the loop; And second thing is that the null pointer exception it may be raising cause you are trying to access the value which is not existing yet. May be my this comment help you